# Problem With the styles export in word document js

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm Try to extract the format of a word document with all my styles but when i export the styles no see in the export document.
i need export all HTML with all styles of my html document but my styles dosen't works

i paste my code.

```js
function generar(element) {
  var preHtml = "<html  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
  var postHtml = "</body></html>";
  let documento = preHtml + document.getElementById(element).innerHTML + postHtml;
  // let documento = '<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">'
  //   +'<head>'
  //   +'  <meta charset="UTF-8">'
  //   +'</head>'
  //   +'<body>'
  //   +  '<h1>Documento 1</h1>'
  //   +  '<p>Prueba de <span style="color: red;">Documento</span> generado con <strong> HTML </strong></p>'
  //   + '</body>'
  //   + '</html>'
  let source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + documento;
  let fileDownload = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(fileDownload);
  fileDownload.href = source;
  fileDownload.download = 'DocumentoWord.doc';
  fileDownload.click();
  document.body.removeChild(fileDownload);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="generar('word')">Generar word</button>
  <div id="word">
    <div style="background-color: #22927da8; border-bottom-right-radius: 133px;">
      <span style="position:absolute; top:70px; right: 100px; left:416px;">
          
            <h4 style="color:rgb(22, 13, 13);">Propuesta </h4>
          </span>

      <div style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><span>
              
              <b style="color:rgb(16, 8, 8);">fecha</b>
          </span>
      </div>
      <div style="position:absolute; right: 137px; top:97px; color:white;">
        Nombre
      </div>
      <div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <span style="color:rgb(14, 7, 7); font-weight: bold;">
          Descripcion
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for all help

Comment: A Word document (`.doc` and `.docx`) is not HTML.

Comment: i try export the html page in a word document